# How do I define website's width only in iPhone's landscape mode (viewport metatag)?

Tags: iphone, html, css, viewport, responsive-design

My website has width set to 460px on iPhone 2G, 3G and 4S in portrait mode. It doesn't look good in horizontal mode though. I would say it should have twice as many pixels.

My current viewport tag looks like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, width=460" />
```

**I want 460px in portrait mode.

I want 800px in landscape mode.**

This is Apple's documentation but horizontal mode is not mentioned: https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html

Comment: And how about any other devices? Should you use percentages instead of fixed values?

Comment: If you can consider applying restriction for your page size in css-styles then i do suggest the `media queries in css`, they can be so much useful when for web page development that targets the various orientation of various devices....

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the constant "device-width"?

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

I've also used the following technique to modify the meta tag after the page has been loaded.  You could likely adapt it to modify the meta tag when the device changes between portrait and landscape:

```
NSString* js = 
@"var img = document.getElementsByTagName( 'img' )[0];" \
"var c = 'width=' + img.width + ', height=' + img.height + ', user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=3.0';" \
"var h = document.createElement( 'head' ); " \
"var m = document.createElement( 'meta' ); " \
"m.setAttribute( 'name', 'viewport' ); " \
"m.setAttribute( 'content', c ); " \
"h.appendChild( m ); " \
"var html = document.getElementsByTagName( 'html' )[0];" \
"var body = document.getElementsByTagName( 'body' )[0];" \
"html.insertBefore( h, body ); " \
"";
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: js ];
```